# delete task scheduler on remote machine using powershell script

Tags: powershell

I want to delete a task scheduler on the remote machine using power shell script. My script

```
$session = New-CimSession -ComputerName "adamix"
Get-ScheduledTask -CimSession $session -TaskPath "\softperfect\" | Disable-ScheduledTask
```

The task folder is located :

```
C:\Windows\Softperfect\soft.exe
```

I want to delete that folder

But my script does not work. What is wrong on my script?

Regards

Comment: There is nothing about removing the folder of the target .exe in your script, you're only trying to disable the task. Is the remote scheduled task successfully disabled?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove a Schedule Task you need to use Unregister-ScheduledTask.
You don't need to pipe Get-ScheduledTask but you still can if you want to.

You also need to tell it not to ask for confirmation each time with `-Confirm:$false`:

```
$session = New-CimSession -ComputerName "adamix"
Unregister-ScheduledTask -CimSession $session -TaskPath "\softperfect" -Confirm:$false
```

You should also make sure that when you create the `CimSession` your user has the correct rights on the remote machine to interact with that ScheduledTask. If you need to pass through different credentials, you can either launch the PowerShell terminal with the required user account or you can use the `-Credential` parameter, like this:

```
# Get-Credential will ask you for a username and password.
$Credential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-CimSession -ComputerName "adamix" -Credential $Credential
Unregister-ScheduledTask -CimSession $Session -TaskPath "\softperfect" -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: Unregister-ScheduledTask : Adamix: No MSFT_ScheduledTask objects found with property 'TaskPath' equal to
'\softperfect'.  Verify the value of the property and retry.
At line:1 char:1
+ Unregister-ScheduledTask -CimSession $Session -TaskPath "\softperfect ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\softperfect:String) [Unregister-ScheduledTask], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound_TaskPath,Unregister-ScheduledTask
    + PSComputerName        : Adamix

Comment: It's saying that the task already doesn't exist. Use `Get-ScheduledTask` on the remote machine to check what the path of your task is. If you want you can use the name of the task instead of the path if you know it, swap out `-TaskPath "\softperfect"` for `-Name <Task Name goes here>`